# How to upload multiple files in <input multiple> with HtmlUnit java

Tags: java, file-upload, htmlunit

I searched the whole day about how to upload more files in HTML `<input type="file" multiple/>` tag with HtmlUnit in Java, but I didn't find out yet.
Can anyone help? I can't modify the web pages, because they're not mine.

I am currently using:

```
HtmlFileInput#setValueAttribute(path);
HtmlFileInput#setContentType(contenType);
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why getting 2 -1? (It's just one now, but still.) Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. It seems that this feature does not exist in HtmlUnit 2.1.13, therefore a feature request ticket was opened: https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/feature-requests/215/

Anyway, I found a way in which a similar behavior can be achieved. Here it is:

```
public static HtmlFileInput insertFileInputWithValue(String name, String value, 
    String contentType, HtmlPage page, DomElement parent) {
  // Necessary, otherwise HtmlUnit doesn't generate HtmlFileInput, but HtmlTextInput by default
  AttributesImpl ai = new AttributesImpl();
  ai.addAttribute(null, null, "type", null, "file");
  ai.addAttribute(null, null, "name", null, name);

  HtmlFileInput input = (HtmlFileInput) HTMLParser.getFactory("input")
    .createElementNS(page, null, "input", ai, true);
  input.setValueAttribute(value);
  input.setContentType(contentType);
  parent.appendChild(input);

  return input;
}
```

These piece of code injects a new html input file in whatever parent you specify, a form most probably.
Even though HtmlUnit doesn't allow using `<input type="file" multiple/>`, the same behavior can be achieved by injecting more HtmlFileInput elements with the same name in your form, in which you set as values the files you want to upload.

I hope this helps.